# Extract Parameters from Blank Gif

Tags: php, parameters, reporting

from the start I want to apologise if this makes no sense I'm having a hard time explaining it.

Based on having a blank.gif on my site I'd like to extract all the Query String Parameters associated to it. The blank.gif is used for tracking purposes so has info such as page viewed, product viewed etc.

For example:

http://reporting.MYSITE.com/cgi-bin/rr/blank.gif?nourl=category-viewed&view_event=yes&view_category=category&view_name=Sale

I'd like to display a widget on the site so the user can see the data which is being passed on the page.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I've seen a site with it on, trying to find the example of it now.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be getting this wrong, but if you just want to extract the query parameter from this URL, use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
foreach (explode('&', parse_url($url)['query']) as $query) {
    $tmp = explode('=', $query);
    $queries[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```

This results in

```
Array
(
    [nourl] => category-viewed
    [view_event] => yes
    [view_category] => category
    [view_name] => Sale
)
```

Comment: That is perfect, exactly the result i want - thank you!

In terms of implementing this into a webpage/widget how could i go about displaying the Array results on the page that someone is viewing?

Does it become an issue that the reporting URL shown above is part of a blank gif within a standard dot com URL?

Sorry for the continuous questions, this is unchartered territory for me

Comment: Could you provide more information on your workflow, e.g. is the URL passed as a parameter?

Comment: Can i message you further information regarding live site URLs etc?

Comment: Do you have an email address to contact on? Wont let me message through your profile on here